# Pass multiple arguments to route/controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to pass two variables/arguments from my view through a link

```
<a href="{{ route('shop.order.test', $id,$form['grouping']) }}"
```

and call the route

```
Route::get('ordering/test', 'Shop\OrderingController@testing')
  ->name('shop.order.test');
```

And call this function with those two arguments

```
public function testing($id,$grouping){

}
```

It doesn't seem to be working though. Is my error in my route or my link call?

Comment: Have you tried passing an array through? instead of comma separated params

Comment: I haven't, I've only done it this way but I have the $id variable separate from the $form array with the grouping element, so I didn't know if I could send them both taht way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have parameters to be passed into controller's method, you need to define route parameters like this

```
Route::get('ordering/test/{id}/{grouping}', 'Shop\OrderingController@testing');
```

then you can have it in controller method:

```
public function testing($id, $grouping)
```

To generate route for above definition, the second parameter is the array of params to pass. So it will become

```
{{ route('shop.order.test', ['id' => $id, 'grouping' => $form['grouping']) }}
```

Comment: @Whisou138 Glad it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

To pass parameters in a route use an array with the paramter names as keys:

```
{{ route('shop.order.test', ['id' => $id, 'grouping' => $form['grouping']]) }}
```

[Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#named-routes)

Comment: `$grouping` should be `$form['grouping']` !